# open jquery popup from ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, firefox

I use jquery pop-up plugin that works perfectly on my page.

But if I call this page from ajax, the Jquery pop-up doesn't works.

Any suggetions?

Thank you very much!!

```
$(document).ready(

function(){
//open popup
$(".pop").click(function(){

var url = $(this).attr('name');

 $("#"+url).fadeIn(1000);
 positionPopup(this);
});

//close popup
$(".close").click(function(){

  var url = $(this).attr('name');


$("#"+url).fadeOut(500);
});
});
```

maybe document.ready didnot call from ajax?
how should I call the function?

Comment: your description is too general. Need to see how the code works.

Comment: how does document.ready fire from ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on` method instead of using just `click`. Your code will be:

```
$(document).ready(

function(){
//open popup
$(document).on("click", ".pop", function(){

var url = $(this).attr('name');

 $("#"+url).fadeIn(1000);
 positionPopup(this);
});

//close popup
$(document).on("click", ".close", function(){

  var url = $(this).attr('name');


$("#"+url).fadeOut(500);
});
});
```

The problem here is about event bubbling. When you create your html elements dynamically with ajax, events are not being attached to them. The `on` method resolves the problem.

Comment: thank you, but it doesnot help. I also see it not recognize js functions on called by ajax page.

Comment: Then you should provide more code :)